# How to pass ansible variables into vagrant

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile

Let's say i have a playbook that i normally run as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -e "var1=val1" \
    -e "hosts=all" \
    -e "devops_dir=$DEVOPS_PATH" \
    -e "cname=something.gooten.com" \
    -v playbook.yml
```

And i want to have this run when i startup a Vagrantfile--

```
  #
  # Run Ansible from the Vagrant Host
  #
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.verbose = "v"
  end
```

How do i add the `-e` variables into the `Vagrantfile` so that they are called as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`extra_vars`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#extra_vars)

```
ansible.extra_vars = {
  var1: val1,
  hosts: all,
  devops_dir: $DEVOPS_PATH,
  cname: something.gooten.com
}
```

Comment: How can I pass an array of object?: `var1: [{foo: 'bar'}, ...]`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to pass arbitrary args to ansible, say `-e` args as well as `-t`, `-v` etc, you can use this trick:

```rb
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    # use args from `ANSIBLE_ARGS` env variable
    ansible.raw_arguments = Shellwords.shellsplit(ENV['ANSIBLE_ARGS']) if ENV['ANSIBLE_ARGS']
  end
```

And then, invoke `vagrant provision` as such:

```bash
ANSIBLE_ARGS="-v -e var1=val1 -t mytag" vagrant provision
```